# Configure logstash to access remote logs

Tags: logstash-configuration, logstash-forwarder, logstash-file

Please can anyone provide me the configuration of logstash to access the log that are located on a remote system. I have tried with IP address, but it says that the plugin failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going to need to set up some sort of shipping method from your remote system to your system, i.e. logstash-forwarder. [Here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-logstash-and-kibana-to-centralize-logs-on-centos-6) is a good guide for getting that set up.

Logstash-forwarder on your remote system will watch any logs that you specify in the logstash-forwarder configuration, and it will ship those logs to your system that is running Logstash server.

Comment: also check FileBeat